# Unit of size returned by java instrumentation

Tags: java, instrumentation

I am using the following java project to determine size of object
http://sizeof.sourceforge.net/

```
public class DataClass /*implements Serializable*/{

    // private static final long serialVersionUID = 5199373516861766638L;
    String name = "GUNJ";
    String lastName= "";

    // int age = 148888890;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DataClass{" +
                "Name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", Last Name='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", Age=" +
                '}';

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // SizeOf.skipStaticField(true);
        // SizeOf.skipFinalField(true);
        // SizeOf.skipFlyweightObject(true);

        System.out.println(SizeOf.humanReadable(SizeOf.deepSizeOf(new DataClass()))); //this will print the object size in bytes
    }

}
```

I get results as below
144Kb, 64Kb, 72Kb

1. Does 'b' here represent bits or bytes?
2. Why does the output not change as I change the number of characters in the above case? Sometimes it increases while sometimes it does not.

It seems to be using Java instrumentation code

Seems to be using the following package: java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation

But not sure whether the APIs of the package returns object size in bits or bytes.

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if it was in bits. Not sure what you're changing when you change the "number of characters", but remember that a `String` reference is just that--a reference.

Comment: These must be bytes, not "Kb", right?

Answer (score 1):

The link you pointed states that:

`Use the humanReadable() method to get the object size in byte, kilo or mega (if you need giga your in trouble guy!):`

So it seems not being in bits.

For your second question I have no answer. I guess String uses buffer with size greater than the size of the string so you can add several chars before the buffer grows in size.

Answer (score 1):

This tool seems a bit outdated. As an alternative I can suggest the excellent [JOL](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/), which has now been released under OpenJDK. 
It's even better than sizeOf and supports many cool features.
Also check out [Shipilev's blog post](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/heapdump-is-a-lie/) which demonstrating the use of this tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t believe that you get results like “144Kb, 64Kb, 72Kb” for such small objects. It’s rather likely that you got `144.0b`, `64.0b`, and `72.0b`.

The [page you have linked](http://sizeof.sourceforge.net/) already says without any room for doubts:

> System.out.println(SizeOf.deepSizeOf()); //this will print the object size in bytes

If you are skeptic about what `SizeOf.humanReadable` does you may simply omit its invocation and print the results of `SizeOf.deepSizeOf` directly.

---

Since `skipStaticField`, `skipFinalField`, `skipFlyweightObject` are three flags, thus allow eight combinations, but you posted only three results without telling the combinations you used, it’s hard to explain the results. Especially, since the implementation of `String` changed between the Java versions and you didn’t specify the used Java version.

When `skipFlyweightObject` is specified, interned `String`s like the literal `String`s in your source code do not count. When it is not specified but `skipFinalField` is, the `String`s flat object storage is accounted but its `char[]` contents is ignored as it is referenced using a `final` field. If all `char`s are counted, you have to consider that most implementations have an object size padding which may be accounted when reporting the object size or not.

It seems that with Oracle’s JVM each object will have an object size that is a multiple of eight bytes. Therefore you may add up to four `UTF-16` characters, before the object size of a `char` array increases to the next multiple of eight bytes.

---

You may use `SizeOf.turnOnDebug();` to get an idea of how the object size has been computed. But you should always keep in mind that such an accumulated size may include objects which are shared between different object graphs and hence add up to a far bigger size than the actually used heap storage.

Also consider what the [documentation of `Instrumentation.getObjectSize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getObjectSize(java.lang.Object)), which is the back-end of this `SizeOf` class, says:

> Returns an implementation-specific approximation of the amount of storage consumed by the specified object. *The result may include some or all of the object's overhead, and thus is useful for comparison within an implementation but not between implementations. The estimate may change during a single invocation of the JVM.* (Emphasis by me)